# Group by repeating values

Tags: sql-server

Table:

[image]

---

```
select 
    MainStationID,
    CONCAT(SUBSTRING(SubStationID,1,2),' STN - ',MainStationID) as Station,
    count(SubStationID) as [COUNT],
    CAST(EndDateTime-StartDateTime AS TIME(0)) AS Duration 
from 
    VHASM2.LineStoppageTrans 
where 
    SubStationID like 'RH%'
group by 
    MainStationID,
    SubStationID,
    CAST(EndDateTime-StartDateTime AS TIME(0)) 
order by 
    MainStationID
```

---

Output:-

[image]

How to get output like this, please help

```
Mainstation   Station     count   Duration [total duration]
   1          RH STN - 1    2     00:01:09
   2          RH STN - 2    3     00:00:13
```

Comment: You have `[Duration] total duration` as a column name but you aren't doing an aggregate on it. You'll want to sum up those seconds and then convert it to a `time` object

Comment: Thank you , what about the count it should be one station record how to get it

Comment: I'm not sure how you got those counts, or why you eliminated the other stations. It looks like you only want mainstation 1 and 2... otherwise, where did they go?

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (MainStationID int, SubStationID varchar(3), StartDateTime datetime, EndDateTime datetime);
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1, 'RH1', '20181219 17:24:08.440', '20181219 17:25:04.523'),
(1, 'RH1', '20181219 17:25:52.283', '20181219 17:26:05.280'),
(2, 'RH2', '20181219 18:36:51.530', '20181219 18:36:57.107'),
(2, 'RH2', '20181219 18:37:03.080', '20181219 18:37:05.090');

;WITH ct AS
(
    SELECT
        MainStationID,
        CONCAT(SUBSTRING(SubStationID, 1, 2), ' STN - ', MainStationID) as Station,
        COUNT(*) as [Count],
        SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, StartDateTime, EndDateTime)) as Duration
    FROM
        @t
    WHERE
        SubStationID LIKE 'RH%'
    GROUP BY
        MainStationID,
        SubStationID
)
SELECT
    MainStationID,
    Station,
    [Count],
    CONCAT(RIGHT('0' + CAST(Duration / 3600 AS varchar(3)), 2), ':',
           RIGHT('0' + CAST((Duration / 60) % 60 AS varchar(3)), 2), ':',
           RIGHT('0' + CAST(Duration % 60 AS varchar(3)), 2)) AS Duration
FROM
    ct
ORDER BY
    MainStationID,
    Station;
```

```
| MainStationID | Station    | Count | Duration |
|---------------|------------|-------|----------|
| 1             | RH STN - 1 | 2     | 00:01:09 |
| 2             | RH STN - 2 | 2     | 00:00:08 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do a SUM on a TIME data type.

You'd need to specify a specific time resolution such as seconds or milliseconds.

For example:

```
select MainStationID,CONCAT(SUBSTRING(SubStationID,1,2),' STN - ',MainStationID) as Station,count(SubStationID) as [COUNT]
,SUM(DATEDIFF(millisecond,StartDateTime, EndDateTime)) AS TotalDurationMS
from VHASM2.VehAssyConveyorLineStoppageTrans
where SubStationID like 'RH%'
group by MainStationID,SubStationID
order by MainStationID
```

Comment: Thank you your comments, how can i get single item without repetation and result should be one line item eg, maintstation count should be 1

Comment: The script I wrote should group by mainstation and substation. The count you see in each row represents the number of instances grouped inside each such pair, but each such pair would only show up once. You won't be able to group only by mainstation, because part of your output is the substation (RH).